# add backslash before quotation in batch script

Tags: batch-file, str-replace

I need to add `\` before every `"` => `\"`.

What I do now:

```
:: log file 
setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
set RESULT={"res1":null,"res2":null,"res3":[6]}
set str=%RESULT:"=!\"!%

echo %str%
```

What I get:

```
{res1:null,res2:null,res3:[6]}
```

What I need:

```
{\"res1\":null,\"res2\":null,\"res3\":[6]}
```

I can not manipulate the RESULT - it is a curl response.

Comment: You replace `"` with the content of the not existing variable `\"`. Try `set "str=%RESULT:"=\"%"` DelayedExpansion is only needed when you set **and** use a variable inside a (code block).

Comment: Thank you so much!